# Connecting with two Android Wear device

Tags: android, wear-os

I have searched a lot before posting this question, but didn't got any satisfactory answer.

My question is - how do i connect with two Android Wear devices at the same time and operate them at the same time. I have such a requirement but unable to proceed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sending the message in wearable you have to use -

```
Node node; // the connected device to send the message to
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
public static final START_ACTIVITY_PATH = "/start/MainActivity";
...

    SendMessageResult result = Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(
            mGoogleApiClient, node, START_ACTIVITY_PATH, null).await();
    if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
        Log.e(TAG, "ERROR: failed to send Message: " + result.getStatus());
    }

private Collection<String> getNodes() {
    HashSet <String>results= new HashSet<String>();
    NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult nodes =
            Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(mGoogleApiClient).await();
    for (Node node : nodes.getNodes()) {
        results.add(node.getId());
    }
    return results;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. One handheld <-> one Wear. It's not a one-to-many connection, it's a one-to-one.

Answer (score 0):

For now there is no way to connect more Wear devices than 1. But as Ashish pointed Message API is ready for that and can handle such situation in the future.